# Please answer this in SOSML

Tags: ml

In SOSML Write the following ML functions using, whenever possible, pattern-matching function definitions.

1. Function union of type 'a list * 'a list → 'a list that returns the union of two lists (in any order).
   For example union ([3, 4, 7, 9, 8, 5], [5, 7, 6, 2, 1, 8, 9]) should return [3, 4, 7, 9, 8, 5, 6, 2, 1] (in any order).
2. Function quicksort of type int list → int list that sorts the given list of integers using the quick-sort algorithm.
   For example: quicksort [3, 4, 7, 9, 8, 5, 6, 2, 1] should return [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9].

In #1 I am getting this error when I run my code on sosml.org: Elaboration failed: Unbound value identifier "member". Here's my code:

```
fun union ([], ys) = ys
  | union (x::xs, ys) = if member (x, ys) then union (xs, ys) else x :: union (xs, ys);

(* Test case for the union function *)
val test_union = union ([3, 4, 7, 9, 8, 5], [5, 7, 6, 2, 1, 8, 9]);
(* Should return a list containing all elements from both lists without duplicates and in any order *)
```

In #2 I am getting this error: val quicksort = fn: ∀ 'b . int list → 'b list;
Execution terminated due to time limit violation

this is my code:

```
fun quicksort [] = []
  | quicksort (x::xs) =
    let
      fun partition (pivot, less, equal, greater) =
        case less of
          [] => (equal, greater)
        | y::ys => if y < pivot then partition (pivot, ys, equal, y::greater)
                   else if y = pivot then partition (pivot, ys, y::equal, greater)
                   else partition (pivot, ys, y::less, greater);

      val (less, greater) = partition (x, [], [x], xs)
    in
      quicksort less @ quicksort greater
    end;
(* Test case for the quicksort function *)
val test_quicksort = quicksort [3, 4, 7, 9, 8, 5, 6, 2];  
(* Should return [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] *)
```

Comment: Welcome Brandon, I'm afraid you might not have read this page: [ask]. Please do, and then come back and edit your question. Else, it could get closed because it does not meet the requirements. And you should change the title too.

Comment: Use small and systematic test cases - not large and arbitrary ones. It's very easy to trace through the code and see that (for instance) `quicksort [1]` can't terminate since it is `quicksort [1] @ quicksort []`.

Comment: And `member` is a function you're supposed to write.

Comment: On an unrelated note: whoever told you that that is quicksort was mistaken – quicksort is an in-place algorithm that uses a constant amount of extra memory. It can't be implemented functionally.